# Invalid field in discord.py embed

Tags: python, discord.py

I am making a control panel channel to toggle cogs. When I try to send an embed, it gives me an error.

The code:

```
emd = discord.Embed(color=0xff0000)
emd.set_author(icon_url=self.client.user.avatar_url, name="Cogs")
for cog in self.client.cogs:
  cog_cmd= ""
    for command in self.client.get_cog(cog).get_commands():
      cog_cmd += f" {command}\n"
      
  emd.add_field(name=f'{cog}:', value=cog_cmd, inline=False)
    
await ctx.send(embed=emd)
```

Console Error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body
In embed.fields.0.value: This field is required
In embed.fields.4.value: This field is required
```

Comment: If Stack Overflow says you have too much code, rather than putting meaningless characters, edit your answer to contain only code that is necessary or add more context to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In embed.fields.0.value: This field is required
> In embed.fields.4.value: This field is required

This is telling you the value parameter where you do `emd.add_field(name=f'{cog}:', value=cog_cmd, inline=False)` can't be an empty string or null. As a workaround if you want to add a field with "no value" you can use the '\u200b' character instead.
So all in all change that line to

```py
emd.add_field(name=f'{cog}:', value=cog_cmd or '\u200b', inline=False)
```